# Graph traversal using every edge

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have a state diagram where each state has a list of other states it can visit. My goal is to generate as many paths as necessary from state Open to state Closed such that every state transition is used.

I'm currently thinking of converting my state table into a graph, then using a graph traversal algorithm to generate my paths. 
Problem is, I don't know if an algorithm exists to fit my exact scenario. I was looking at Eulerian paths, which hit every edge only once if possible. This is not ideal because there are multiple nodes that only have a way in and no way out.
Then, I was thinking of using Bellman Ford to generate paths to these closed nodes, and removing edges used in these paths and running it again.

Hopefully I described the problem well enough, let me know if there's something I can do. Thanks.

Comment: You want to enumerate all (acyclic?) paths from node Open to node Closed in a graph?

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_inspection_problem (this used to have the colorful name of the Chinese Postman Problem, but it looks like Wikipedia doesn't like to call it by that name)

Comment: @Patrick87 yes, kind of. I'm more looking to enumerate as many paths as I need to contain all possible state transitions. So I'm picturing a digraph, where I need to traverse every edge of the digraph using ideally one path, but multiple paths if necessary. Edges can be traversed more than once if necessary to reach other untraversed edges.

Comment: @mcdowella This is close to what I need, although my graph is directed.